# InstallShield - Condition for Component

Tags: components, conditional-statements, installshield

I am currently struggling with an custom property (defined in VBScript as Custom Action) and the usage as Condition for an Component:

Property = MYDOMAIN

**MSI Log entries:**

```
PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying MYDOMAIN property. Its current value is '0'. Its new value: '999'.

Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION;USERNAME;COMPANYNAME;ISX_SERIALNUM;SUPPORTDIR;INSTALLDIR;MYDOMAIN
MYDOMAIN = 999
```

The component condition looks like:

```
MYDOMAIN="999"
```

The Component is not installed during install process, I made several variations:

```
MYDOMAIN<<"999"
MYDOMAIN<<999
MYDOMAIN=999
```

Anybody there who can enlight me what I am doing wrong here?
When no condition is defined the component is being installed.

Cheers
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?138196-component-condition-not-working

Moved the Custom Action with the Property definition to an earlier position within the sequence.
Everything seems to work now :)